# Implementing a Binary Search Tree for Strings in C

Tags: c, string, binary-search-tree

I am attempting to implement a BST for strings in C.
I am very new to C, coming from a java background so please  forgive my errors.
My node declaration looks as follows.

```
struct node {
    char *word;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

static struct node *root = NULL;
```

I'm then trying to simply add a node to the start of the tree
This is my code so far.

```
int ws_add_word(char *word)
{
int n;
struct node *tmp = root;

// check if word is alrady there
n = strcmp(word, (*tmp)->word);
if (word_tree == NULL){
    (*root)->word = word;
    return 1;
} else if (n == 0){ //word present
    return 1;
} else if(n > 0){ //word bigger add to right
    if ((*root)->right == NULL){
        (*root)->right = word;
        return 1;
    }
} else if(n < 0){ //word smaller add to left
    if ((*root)->left == NULL){
        (*root)->left = word;
        return 1;
    }
}

// if tree full return false, else true
if (word_count >= tree_size){
    return 0;
} else{
    return 1;
}
}
```

The code simply needs to return a 1 if it manages to insert the word and a 0 if it doesn't insert the word.

I'm receiving the error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct node') n = strcmp(word, (*tmp)->word);
it doesn't look like it's accepting the '->' and I don't know how to reference the data that is in the node.
When I was doing this with numbers using int instead of char, it was working great.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [It's not so hard to google the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=invalid%20type%20argument%20of%20%27-%3E%27), especially when it's a very common, trivial syntax error.

Comment: You've already been answered, but it looks like root is set to NULL at the beginning and you aren't handling the NULL case in your code.  This will likely cause a crash once your code compiles.

Comment: @H2CO3: and soon enough people who do google it will find this page.  Good thing someone put the correct answer on this page.

Answer (score 2):

`a->b` already dereferences `a`, what you need is `tmp->word`,

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your logic:

If you have an object of type `(struct node *)`, then to access it's members, you should do one of the following:

```
Option 1: (*foo).member
Option 2: foo->member
```

Not both.

Comment: `s/should/can`, and the "should" applies to #2 only.

Answer (score 0):

Little tip:
If you declare structures use typedef it's making your code prettier:

```
typedef struct node_t {
char *word;
struct node *left;
struct node *right;
}; *node; 
node root = NULL;
```